# c# checking process status

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to create a program that should start 10 processes in successive order. In order to do that I need to check for the process status.

I was wondering how i could check for this status.

I know this question has been asked some times before. but what I require is to check whether the application is still starting up or if it's already running.

Because over time the programs i want to start up will probably take longer to load as more data is being retrieved. so a simple Timer would not suffice..

I hope i'm being clear here. (btw the programs are supposed to run for an unlimited amount of time).

==Edit==

What I'm using is System.Diagnostics for the process to start.

What i mean with is running/ starting up is the following.
imagine an very big program loading. initially the only indication you have of the program starting is your mouse.  This could be dubbed as the program starting up.

What I mean with the program running is when you can use it.

```
Double click .exe => Program Loading => Program ready to use
                  => Starting up     => Running
```

Comment: What are you using to start the processes? Are you spinning up new background workers? http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is already running"? Main exe loaded? Exe and all dependent dlls? Including the delay-loaded? No disk activity for a span of time?